# Error when using 'ansible-local' provisioner with Docker container

Tags: docker, ansible, packer

I'm getting an error when running the `ansible-local` provisioner with a docker builder in Hashicorps Packer.

My template (template.json):

```
{
  "builders": [
        {
            "type": "docker",
            "image": "ubuntu",
            "commit": "true"
        }
    ],
   "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "inline": ["sudo apt-get update"]
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "script": "setup_ansible.sh"
        },
        {
            "type": "ansible-local",
            "playbook_file": "./kubeadm.yml"
        }
   ]
}
```

The error:

```
docker: Executing Ansible: cd /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible-local/5a8f3bad-8413-16c3-b255-6a06a9076ef3 && ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=1 PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 ansible-playbook /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible-local/5a8f3bad-8413-16c3-b255-6a06a9076ef3/kubeadm.yml --extra-vars \"packer_build_name=docker packer_builder_type=docker packer_http_addr=\"  -c local -i /tmp/packer-provisioner-ansible-local/5a8f3bad-8413-16c3-b255-6a06a9076ef3/packer-provisioner-ansible-local135505282
docker: ERROR! the playbook: packer_builder_type=docker could not be found
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is some [bug](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/5885) in Hashicorps Packer 1.2.0, consider downgrading or upgrading to v1.2.1, comments in GH issue page confirm that the deployed fix is working.